# Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all polynomials. Let $D : \mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{P}$ be a derivative mapping, show that $\text{im}D= \mathcal{P.}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all polynomials $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ defined with addition and scalar multiplication. Let $D : \mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{P}$ be a derivative mapping, show that $\operatorname{im}D= \mathcal{P.}$

I've previously posted a similar question regarding the set of polynomials at most degree $n$. Now, this seems to be a generalization for the set of all polynomials?

For the image of $D$ I have that $\operatorname{im}D=\{Dp(x) \mid p(x) \in \mathcal{P} \}$ right? What I don't understand here is that the derivative operator applied to $p(x)$ outputs a polynomial of degree $n-1$ so how can $\operatorname{im}D = \mathcal{P}$ when it seems that $\operatorname{im}D = \mathcal{P_{n-1}}$?

Comment: If the domain is $\mathcal P_n$, then the image is indeed $P_{n-1}$. What if the domain is $\mathcal P$?

Comment: My confusion seems to be not understanding what $\mathcal{P}$ is then? From the problem statement, it seems that $\mathcal{P}$ would be the set of polynomials of degree $n$?

Comment: Aha, well articulated, and it's not written 100% clearly. To me, the $n$ in the definition of $\mathcal P$ is itself variable—it can take on lots of different values just as the coefficients $a_i$ can. (But I agree that if we intended to restrict to polynomials of degree exactly $n$, the notation would be extremely similar ... we math writers need to use our words as well as symbols!) To me "all polynomials" hints that $n$ is variable, whereas I would write "all degree-$n$ polynomials" if the other meaning were intended.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be true.  By any definition of "a derivative mapping" (a.k.a. derivation, i.e. a map $D$ which is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and which satisfies the Leibniz rule $D(fg) = f (Dg) + G (df)$) that I know, $p \mapsto x p'$ should count as a derivation, and 1 is not in the image of that derivation.

Comment: The problem statement is not well written. What include "with addition and scalar multiplication" when that has nothing to do with the image of the mapping? Unless, that is, what is meant is the mapping is a $\,\mathbb{R}-\,$linear mapping and we have to prove that the $\,D\,$ function is actually $\,\mathbb{R}-\,$linear. If $\,D\,$ is the usual derivative function for polynomials then this may or may not be assumed as given.

Comment: @Somos $D$ is given to be the usual derivative function for polynomials in this case.

Comment: In that case, the mapping $\,D\,$ has an inverse mapping "formal indefinite integral" of a polynomial which is defined for all polynomials. Hence the mapping $\,D\,$ is onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$\mathcal P = \Bbb R[x], \tag 0$

and hence contains all polynomials of every degree.  Thus:

For any

$b \in \Bbb R\tag 1$

and any

$\displaystyle \sum_0^n a_ix^i \in \Bbb R[x] = \mathcal P \tag 2$

we have

$D \left ( \displaystyle \sum_0^n \dfrac{a_i}{i + 1}x^{i + 1} + b \right ) =  \displaystyle \sum_0^n a_ix^i, \tag 3$

and we see that

$D: \mathcal P \to \mathcal P \tag 4$

is surjective; that is

$\text{im} \; D = \mathcal P = \Bbb R[x]. \tag 5$